# How do I raise a `uom` quantity as a power of `e`?

Tags: rust

Using the rust crate `uom`, how do I raise a quantity as a power of the dimensionless quantity `e`?

```rust
use uom::si::f32::*;
use uom::si::length::kilometer;

fn main() {
   let length = Length::new::<kilometer>(5.0);
   let answer = std::f32::consts::E.pow(length); // doesn't compile
}
```

Comment: i checked the source code of uom, are you sure this library support what you need here?
you have two option first use ```powf``` rather than ```pow```, second import ```Pow``` trait with following code ```use uom::num_traits::Pow;```

remember ```Pow``` not support Length and Quantity as input

Comment: Note that mathematically it doesn't make sense to compute `e^l` when `l` is a length. You would need have some reference length `ref_l` and compute `e ^ (l / ref_l)`.

Comment: Ah darn, I oversimplified my minimal example: it's not actually a length, its something more complicated then that (the `answer` type is a pressure value in the end). Perhaps I should redo my question a bit. I'll check out the num_traits though thanks!